# How to use a duration in code from a google sheet on Google Apps Script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, duration

Right now I'm making a spreadsheet to track how much time I spend at school bored, and for days where I spend over 2 hours bored I want it to display in the cell like this: "2:31:00 (bored!)". However, I cannot figure out how to use a duration for a calculation in Apps Scripts. This is what I have so far:

```
function BORED(value) {
  if(value>= x )    {      //* the x next to the value statement is where my duration goes *//
    return "(bored!)";
  }
}
```

What do I do?

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: What is your concern? How to subtract two hour values? how to write in your sheet?

Comment: It depends on how you are inputing your duration. What is the input format?